# Finding namespace of a given Element using VTD-XML

Tags: vtd-xml

For my application I only need to determine the namespace of the root node, so ideally I would like to execute a single operation to get this namespace.

I have code that uses an XPath to get all of the namespaces declared (`/*/namespace::*`), but then I have to go through them all and do vn.toRawString for each one to compare it to my prefix, which I would like to avoid.

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious here, but what is the best way to get the namespace of a given element, since xmlns: attributes are not considered in getAttrValNS ?

```
String elementName = vn.toRawString(vn.getCurrentIndex());

String prefix = prefix(elementName);
String localName = localName(elementName);

QName rootQName;
if (prefix == null) {
    rootQName = new QName(localName);
} else {
    int nsIndex = vn.getAttrValNS("xmlns", prefix);

    // Can't find index because xmlns attributes are not included

    String namespace =  vn.toRawString(nsIndex);
    rootQName = new QName(namespace, localName);
}
```

Is there a simple XPath that will just give me the namespace of the root node, not ALL namespaces DECLARED on the root node?

Comment: I think vtd-xml supports xpath functions such as namespace-uri(node-set?) which you may want to look into...

Comment: That did the trick.  `AutoPilot ap = new AutoPilot(vn);
        ap.selectXPath("namespace-uri(.)");
        String ns = ap.evalXPathToString();`

Answer (score 1):

```
AutoPilot ap = new AutoPilot(vn);
ap.selectXPath("namespace-uri(.)");
String ns = ap.evalXPathToString();
```